# deprecated_instruction error upon contract deployment

Tags: smart-contracts

I'm attempting to clone some contracts that are available on mainnet and deploy them to Ghostnet. When trying to deploy the Hic et Nunc Marketplace (https://tzstats.com/KT1HbQepzV1nVGg8QVznG7z4RcHseD5kwqBn), I've been running into the following issue:

`failed to deploy contract: tezos: kind=permanent, id=proto.017-PtNairob.michelson_v1.deprecated_instruction, reason=`

What's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This script uses the `SUB` instruction on type `mutez`. This variant of the `SUB` instruction has been deprecated in Ithaca and the `SUB_MUTEZ` instruction should now be used instead.

Comment: Thank you. After amending the contract code to use the `SUB_MUTEZ` instruction instead of the deprecated `SUB` variant, I'm now facing the following error:

```id=proto.017-PtNairob.michelson_v1.undefined_binop```

Comment: Please open another question and give the original and modified Michelson scripts.